# Filtering by file type or name in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

If I want to find just image files using the Microsoft Graph API. Is there a way to filter using $filter? By file type or name "endswith"?

I try

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{MyID}.sharepoint.com/lists/{Drive ID}/items?$filter=endswith(webUrl, '.png')`

but got this error

`"message": "Item not found",`

but there is an image (.png) file contain in the drive
, My goal is to get response all of image file that contain in Drive in Sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I agree that there is no `name` property populated in the response even if its documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) that there is a `name` property. And all properties doesn't support all ODATA query parameters as far as I know.

But you can do one thing. There is a fields relationship which you can use to get the filename with extension. Use the query below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com/lists/8f7fc3c2-8d9b-4563-94c8-b63bf0f19ebc/items?$expand=fields
```

Pick that `LinkFilename` property from `fields` property and you can filter it on your end(by writing code) easily.

[image]